# TZipForge + ExtracttoStream

Tags: delphi

I have downloaded TZipforge to try it before buying.

I have some troubles with the function ExtractToStream(...) as it gives me 
an 0015 error (file not found), although my code is written like this:

curdir is current directory.
Archiver is Tzipforge

It is basically the original sourcecode from Component Ace with some minor modifications made by me.

```
procedure TfmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR
   TStr : String;
   Ts   : TStream;
begin
   Ts := TStream.Create();
   with Archiver do
      begin
         FileName := Curdir + '\Archive\test.zip';
         showmessage(FileName);
         Password := 'testing';
         OpenArchive();           // open an existing archive file

         ExtractToString('forsiden.html',TStr);

         showmessage('filename =  ' + filename);

         if FileExists('C:\test\zipper\archive\test.zip') then
            BEGIN
               ExtractToStream('C:\test\zipper\archive\test.zip',TS);
                         (*     c:\TEST\ZIPPER\Archive\ *)
            END;

        CloseArchive;
        Ts.free;
      end;
    ShowMessage('All files were extracted successfully.');
end;
```

I have (for test purposes) included `ExtracttoStream-function` in the original BASIC example, but I still get the '0015 error` .

I do not know what I am doing wrong ...  The file is present (where it should be) and the program (routine) still says 'file not found '.   "

Comment: A comment on the question. You've left in much needless code, calls to ShowMessage and the like. Such questions are better when tightly focused with minimal code samples.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should start off by trusting your components. It tells you that the file is not found. Let's work on the assumption that is correct. Your call was:

```
ExtractToStream('C:\test\zipper\archive\test.zip',TS);
```

The first argument of the name of the zipped file contained in the archive. But you have supplied the archive file name. You already specified the archive file name when you assigned to `Archiver.FileName`. The archive file was opened when you called `Archiver.OpenArchive`. So, there's no reason why you would need to supply the archive file name again.

The archive does not contain a file named `'C:\test\zipper\archive\test.zip'`. The message is not informing you that the archive file does not exist, rather that the file that you are trying to extract does not exist.

It looks like you are actually trying to extract `'forsiden.html'` from the archive. So the correct call will be:

```
ExtractToStream('forsiden.html',TS);
```

This will also fail though, because of another mistake in your code. You must never instantiate `TStream`. That's an abstract base class. You must instantiate a concrete stream class such as `TMemoryStream` or `TFileStream`.

I must also urge you to use `try/finally` to ensure that you don't leak objects whose lifetime you are charged with managing.

And finally, can I register distrust of the `with` statement. This has been discussed many times, and a modicum of websearch will reveal many articles on the subject. Perhaps you got away with it this time, but it will bite you at some point.

Comment: Heffeman:  I modified the cod according to your (very good advices). And it worked (Thans a lot ! )    With the "WITH"- statement I,m a

Comment: Heffenan:   Sorry, I see now, that  the answer I gave earlier has been in some way shortened. I am very glad in WITH's and I use them when ever applicable.  the code is (was) NOT optimized (at all) - just for a test.  Again THANK YOU  for your supervision.

Comment: As far as `with` goes, it's a really bad idea. You won't be at all happy with it when you fall foul of the traps that it sets for you. Anyway, it's obviously up to you.